# Why density in android_avd_detials differs from getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density

Tags: android

In my android, avd density is `120`, but when I am calculating it with the help of  `getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density` it is `.75`.

Why they are different ?

Answer (score 1):

The AVD density value is the DPI (dots per inch) bucket that the device falls in, one of:

```
LDPI   120
MDPI   160
HDPI   240
XHDPI  320
XXHDPI 480
```

The DisplayMetrics density value is the fraction of the base density (MDPI). 1 DP (device-independent pixel) is equal to 1 pixel at MDPI density, and 1 * the fractional density for all others.

If you just want to get the equivalent DPI value, there is another field in DisplayMetrics called `densityDpi`.